# bash: cannot execute binary file exec format error fortran

Tags: bash, fortran, gfortran

When I run the code given below, it always gives me the following error:

```
bash: cannot execute binary file exec format error fortran
```

Also, the file "file" is not being created at the location mentioned in the code. I've a 64-bit processor and 64-bit version of Ubuntu 16.04, so that does not appear to be the issue. Can someone please point out where I'm wrong?

```
program sandpile_model
 implicit none

integer, parameter :: len = 20
integer, dimension(len,len) :: square
!real, dimension(len,len) :: blah
!open(unit=1,file="\\home\\sandpile\\fortran\\file")

!dummy variables
integer :: i,j,d

do i=1,len
   do j=1,len
      square(i,j)=2
   end do
end do


do d=1,10000
   square((len/2)-1,(len/2)-1)=square((len/2)-1,(len/2)-1)+1
   if(square((len/2)-1,(len/2)-1)>3) then
      call toppling((len/2)-1,(len/2)-1)
   end if
end do

!open(unit=1,file="\\home\\sandpile\\fortran\\file")
 do i=1,len
   do j=1,len
      write(1,*), i,'\t',j,'\t',square(i,j)
   end do
   print*, '\n' 
end do

end program sandpile_model





!This subroutine specifies the evolution rules of the model
recursive subroutine toppling(x,y) 
 !implicit none

integer, parameter :: len = 20
integer, dimension(len,len) :: square
!real, dimension(len,len) :: blah
integer, intent(in) :: x,y


square(x,y)=square(x,y)-4
square(x+1,y)=square(x+1,y)+1
if(square(x+1,y)>3) then
   call toppling(x+1,y)
end if
square(x-1,y)=square(x-1,y)+1
if(square(x-1,y)>3) then
   call toppling(x-1,y)
end if
square(x,y+1)=square(x,y+1)+1
if(square(x,y+1)>3) then
   call toppling(x,y+1)
end if
square(x,y-1)=square(x,y-1)+1
if(square(x,y-1)>3) then
   call toppling(x,y-1)
end if

end subroutine toppling
```

Comment: How are you running your code, i.e. which commands are you giving.

Comment: by "./try.o" try.o is the executable file

Comment: How did you create `try.o`?

Comment: "gfortran -c try.f90"

Comment: This is creating an object not an executable. In this case try `gfortran try.f90`

Comment: what will be the executable then? Will it be try.o or something else?

Comment: The executable name will be`a.out`or `a.exe` depending on your environment. With the -o flags with gfortran you can specify an other name. Please check the compiler documentation e.g. starting with `man gfortran

Comment: Thanks a ton! Apologies it turned out to be such a stupid mistake :)

Comment: Welcome. Use tag [tag:fortan] for all Fortran questions. You will get MUCH more attention. Also take the Welcome [tour] to find out about the features of this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem appears here that an attempt is made to run an object file and not an executable.

Very small / limited instructions:

- To create an object file: `gfortran -c <fortran file>`
- To create an executable: `gfortran <fortran file>`

When using multiple source files:

- Create objects from the individual files and link the together by means of `gfortran <object files>`
- Create executable directly from source files `gfortran <fortran files>`

Note:

- order of the files might be important
- It might be necessary to link libraries as well into the executable (`-l option)
- Name of the output file can be specified by means of the `-o`option

Further initial reading:

- compiler documentation
- `man gfortran`
- `man make` for automation in more complex situations.